# mongolab's REST API auto increment field in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, post, auto-increment, mlab

I want to insert new record with incrementing counter field using REST api provided by mongolab.com

Ex:

**Post-method REST call 1:**

POST /api/1/databases/thedatabase/collections/Member?apiKey=xXxxxxXXXxxxxXXXxxxxXXXXxxxXXXXxxX HTTP/1.1
Host: api.mongolab.com
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 4c66f955-758a-81e4-484e-89408d643eba
{
     "name":"Jack"
}

**Post-method REST call 2:**

POST /api/1/databases/thedatabase/collections/Member?apiKey=xXxxxxXXXxxxxXXXxxxxXXXXxxxXXXXxxX HTTP/1.1
Host: api.mongolab.com
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 4c66f955-758a-81e4-484e-89408d643eba
{
     "name":"John"
}

I want this to effect as    **{ "_id": 1, "name":"Jack" } , { "_id":2, "name":"John" }**

**Tried using $inc operator, getNextSequence() methods but not working for mongolab.com's REST API.**

Anybody with solution?

Comment: what error are you getting? Also you should format your code better.

Comment: Since I'm using Mongolab.com's REST api, I'm refering their documentation. For auto increment they don't have anything but I tried using $inc operator which is used in shell way of accessing data.